# fuzzy matching among three lists based of some value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, fuzzywuzzy

```
list1 = [
    {'name': 'best value in town', 'value': 23, 'more_key': 'more values'},
    {'name': 'best Hero town', 'value': 'asdf', 'more_key': 'more values'},
    {'name': 'best Hero in town', 'value': 4, 'more_key': 'more values'},
    {'name': 'best town Hero ', 'value': 24, 'more_key': 'more values'},
    ...
]
list2 = [
    {'name': 'best value in town', 'value': 212, 'more_key': 'more values'},
    {'name': 'best zcv in town', 'value': 2323, 'more_key': 'more values'},
    ...
]

list3 = [
    {'name': 'best value in town', 'value': 2376, 'more_key': 'more values'}, 
    {'name': 'best test in town', 'value': 2376, 'more_key': 'more values'},

    ...
]
```

i have 3 lists of dict each n size

i needs to match `name` value among them something like using `fuzzywuzzy` if the match ratio is above some percentage that results should be combined as one other results can be left as it is

output sample

```
[{"list1": {"name": "best value in town", "value": 23, "more_key": "more values"}, "list2": {"name": "best Hero in town", "value": 212, "more_key": "more values"}, "list3": {"name": "best Hero in town", "value": 2376, "more_key": "more values"}},
{"list1": {"name": "best value in town", "value": 23, "more_key": "more values"}, "list2": {"name": "best Hero in town", "value": 212, "more_key": "more values"}},
{"list1": {"name": "i am differnt then list2 & list3 ", "value": 24, "more_key": "more values"}}
]
```

i am able to write the code but i need solution which is memory & time efficient code as lists can be of size million

Comment: Why is the output consisting out of 3 dicts each with a different amount of lists? Your output appears like you simply want to remove duplicates from each list of dicts without combining them in any way. Is this correct?

Comment: @maxbachmann no i want to combine them as well based on the value of "name" field matched with fuzzywuzzy

Comment: For me it is not clear how they are combined inside output. It seems to be the same dicts as before with `duplicates` removed.

Comment: @maxbachmann let me try to explain you for example if we have same name in list1, list2, list3 that results should become one as a dict  where 'key' will be the list name and value would be corresponding dict .. if any of the dict name doesn't match that remains alone in the output list